# My ASP.Net webforms button is not firing?

Tags: asp.net

I thought this would be relatively simple, but I have a simple button on my Site.Master page that I want to use to get cell info from a grid and then post it to a textbox. However it doesn't seem to be firing (not hitting break points). I've tried cleaning the solution and disabling CausesValidation. The Button1_Click function also appears under the drop down menu for Click in the buttons event property..

Here's the main chunk of my form:

```
    <div id="logindisplay">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
    </div> 

    <div id="menucontainer">

        <ul id="menu">              
            <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
            <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Director" HeaderText="Director" SortExpression="Director" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="DateReleased" HeaderText="DateReleased" SortExpression="DateReleased" />
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" CausesValidation="True" />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                     </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>

              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Movies]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select Movies" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="Button1_Click" CausesValidation="False" />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  Text="First Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </form>
```

and heres my small Master.Site.cs:

```
namespace MovieApp
{

    public partial class Site : System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage
    {
        private System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<GridViewRow> Selections;


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i;
            TextBox box = (form1.FindControl("TextBox1")) as TextBox;
            box.Text = "!!!";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            GridView gView = (GridView)(form1.FindControl("GridView1")); 
            GridViewRow row = gView.Rows[0];

            TextBox box = (form1.FindControl("TextBox1")) as TextBox;
            box.Text= row.Cells[0].Text;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing MVC and WebForms. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using ASP.NET MVC.

You cannot use WebControls or Control Events in ASP.NET MVC - it uses a completely different programming paradigm compared to Web Forms, the only thing it has in common is using aspx/ascx files for storing prewritten HTML.

If you want to use a "button event" workflow in your actions then look for the button's `value=""` attribute in your `Request.Form` collection.

Answer (score 0):

remove OnClientClick="Button1_Click" 
-OnClientClick is used to call client side functions (javascript functions)

Answer (score 0):

You know it is entirely different programming method in MVC compared to web applications. 
In MVC view is used to design page. Here.. it is better to use html button insted of server control
button.  .  Whatever you need to do... it should be defined in controller class([http post]... ActionResult). You are actually mixing the code. That is not good.... Try this way